# Incomplete jpg or image files?

Tags: images, file-transfer, jpeg

One of my tools didn't work properly and I have a lot of image files that aren't complete (50%, 70%, it varies). What is a command line tool or lib (C++ or .NET, .NET preferred if not command line) to check if an image file is completed or not? I can see part of the image when I open it but it is obviously not complete so I'd like to delete them all and restart my tool.

Comment: Which formats other than JPG? If there's an EOF marker or the header includes (expected) file size information, it might be possible to check for those. For JPGs, [JpegInfo](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2352/find-corrupted-jpeg-image-files) should help; also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198438/efficiently-detect-corrupted-jpeg-file).

Comment: @Karan: Good i'll use that, but... i'm on windows. I think i can figure something out using my linux VM so +1. I'll wait for a bit before solving

Answer (score 2):

imagemagick identify with `-regard-warnings -verbose` does the job (stderr msg at end)